# How to send email with attachment from Azure Web Site using office365 account

Tags: c#, azure, office365, azure-web-app-service, smtpclient

I have office 365 account, using it I want to send emails with attachment inside my web application which is deployed in Azure Web Site.

Answer (score 0):

This is the function for doing it

```
 public void SendEmailWithAttachment()
        {
            var objMailMessage = new MailMessage("EnterFromEmailAddress", "ReceiverEmailAddress")
            {
                Subject = "EnterEmailSubject",
                IsBodyHtml = true,
                Body = "EnterEmailBody"
            };
            //You can add more attachments
            objMailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("EnterAttachmentLocationPath")); 
            var smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com");
            var login = new NetworkCredential("SenderEmail","SenderEmailPAssword");
            smtp.Credentials = login;
            smtp.Port =  587;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true; 
            smtp.Send(objMailMessage); 
        }
```

**It is better to keep or credentials in web.config as App Settings.**